# apostrophe symbol, euro sign and pound sign not fetching exactly from remote text file

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, bufferedreader, android-fonts

In my android application i am fetching the content of text file from a remote location. The code is below

```
        URL textUrl;
        try {
        textUrl = new URL("http://myurl/data.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));
        String StringBuffer;

        while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

            list.add(StringBuffer);

        }
        bufferReader.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    return list;
```

My issue is i am not getting the exact data.The data in the file is

> USA|US 100’s/50’s|1.23|| 0 |
>
> |US $ 20/10/5|1.23|1.259| 0 |1.259
>
> |USTC|0.00|0.00| 0 |0.00
>
> JPN|Japan Yen 1,000|1.20|1.247| 0 |0.00
>
> GBP|GBP  £ 1 |2.08|2.116| 0 |0.00
>
> EUR|Euro  € 1 unit|1.705|1.731| 0 |0.00

And the data i am getting is

> USA|US 100�s/50�s|1.23|| 0 |
>
> |US $ 20/10/5|1.23|1.259| 0 |1.259
>
> |USTC|0.00|0.00| 0 |0.00
>
> JPN|Japan Yen 1,000|1.20|1.247| 0 |0.00
>
> GBP|GBP  � 1 |2.08|2.116| 0 |0.00
>
> EUR|Euro  � 1 unit|1.705|1.731| 0 |0.00

The apostrophe symbol, euro sign and pound sign are replaced by � symbol.

I am getting the same result in both emulator and device.

I can not do anything in the remote txt file.

How can i get the exact data?

Comment: Text file should be formatted- Html, UTF-8. Eg. euro sign could be : &euro;

Comment: How try saving data file as UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: The txt file should be UTF-8 encoded. That's all. Decent text editors allow you to "Save As".

Comment: I can not do anything with the txt file. Is there anything i can do from the application side..

Comment: 1. Figure out the encoding used in the file. For example, examine the byte values of those non-ASCII characters. 2. Use the same encoding when reading the file in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

1) Figure out the encoding used in the file, as @laalto said . Here the encoding was "windows-1252".

2)Then edited the code as

```
 BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream(), "windows-1252"));
```

It is working fine for me.

Comment: How did you figure the right encoding? Mine is clearly not windows-1252